# Possible interaction issue between Django 1.7.4 and django-cacheops 2.2.1

Tags: python, django, django-1.7, django-cache

I am upgrading a django app from 1.6 to 1.7. The app uses `django-cacheops` to store the results of a query. After the switch to Django 1.7 the following error is raised on all requests but the first one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/virtualenv/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/data/virtualenv/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tracking/middleware.py", line 131, in process_response
    visitor = self._refresh_visitor(user, request, now)
  File "/data/virtualenv/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tracking/middleware.py", line 60, in _refresh_visitor
    visitor = Visitor.objects.get(pk=session_key)
  File "/data/virtualenv/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cacheops/query.py", line 398, in get
    return self.get_queryset().inplace().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/virtualenv/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cacheops/query.py", line 295, in get
    return qs._no_monkey.get(qs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/virtualenv/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 353, in get
    return clone._result_cache[0]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_result_cache'
```

When the `AttributeError` is raised `clone` is list with a single item, but it [`django.db.models.query` the attribute `_result_cache` to be that list](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7.4/django/db/models/query.py#L353).

In the [`django-cacheops` method that calls that function](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops/blob/2.2.1/cacheops/query.py#L295) `self`'s type is `CacheQuerySet`.

My suspicion is that the source of this problem is that the `django` code expects a `QuerySet` object and the duck `CacheQuerySet` is not quite matching the expectation of `QuerySet`.

It's also possible something is configured incorrectly. Here are pertinent settings:

```
CACHEOPS_REDIS = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 6379,
    'db': 10,
    'socket_timeout': 3,
}

CACHEOPS = {
    'core.vantageuser': {'ops':'count', 'timeout':60*2},
    'core.banditarm': {'ops':'all', 'timeout':60*2},
    'core.armmembership': {'ops':'all', 'timeout':60*60*2},
}

CACHEOPS_FAKE = False
CACHEOPS_DEGRADE_ON_FAILURE = True
```

Is this a real issue that should be reported to `django-cacheops`? Anyone have any ideas to bypass the issue (other than settings `CACHEOPS_FAKE=True`)?

[EDIT]:

[My friend was able to replicate the issue with a bare minimum repo](https://github.com/dvincelli/buggy/tree/master). The issue seem to stem from the `django-tracking2` package.

No solution yet, but working on it.

Comment: The solution is stop using `django-tracking2`, it's broken. And it duplicates what cacheops does anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed an error in your config `'ops':'count'` should be spelled as `'ops':['count']` (people will do this anyway, so next version of cacheops will understand that). This is, however, shouldn't cause the error you are receiving.

Your issue is most probably coming from another package besides cacheops messing with `QuerySet`. So check if anything monkey patches or subclasses it. Pay particular attention if `__getitem__()` is tampered with.

If you can't spot where this is coming from I suggest you make "shit to sweet" dismantling of your project: remove third-party apps and your code until everything starts to work and then pay attention at the last step. If it still won't work you then could create an issue on github and attach what's left of your project there.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I created a new bare minimum django project with `django-cacheops` and `django-tracking2` and was able to replicate the issue. I suspect I [found the culprit](https://github.com/bruth/django-tracking2/blob/master/tracking/cache.py#L16-L340). I'll update if I find a solution.

Comment: Also Suor, the [README of `django-cacheops`](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops/blob/80051209dfb19318afdfdafb6461632f21d2829e/README.rst) has some examples of  `'ops': 'all'` (such as line #71).

Comment: `'all'` is not an op to cache it's a shortcut for a `['fetch', 'get', 'count', 'exists']`. I know it's confusing.

Comment: On `tracking2`, this is definitely it. It fills queryset internal storage, then slicing makes `clone` a list so you get attribute error. Actually, this should err even if cacheops if disabled.